# How to block Outlook calender for next 24 hours?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I would like my Outlook calendar to always show myself as busy for the next 24 hours.  The goal is to prevent people from scheduling a meeting for the same day.  Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you just create a fictitious meeting and have it last 24h?

Comment: @terdon Post that as an answer :D

Comment: It needs to be rolling - I don't want to have to update the meeting manually every 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Create an event/appointment in Outlook, but not as you'd expect to.

If you set it as an **All Day Event** then it goes to the top of the calendar, and annoyingly people will probably not notice it and thus book appointments for you.

So what I suggest you do is **make an appointment from 00:00 to 23:59** then you won't have to update it every half an hour, or I have I got the wrong end of the stick?

Once you have done this you can **copy by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and pressing C**, click on the next day and paste holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>V</kbd>